# Detailed gestures predicted with simple horizontal lines

Tags: android, gesture

I have a collection of Greek letters in a gesture library and for some reason swiping straight left or right comes up with a pretty good score for mu and iota, neither of which represent horizontal lines. This breaks the idea of my app. I'm currently using a score of 25 or higher to test accuracy of drawing the letters.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on your problem..

Comment: So I've "fixed" this by adding a horizontal line as a gesture and including code to say the drawing failed if it matches that line more than anything else. I'm not sure if that's a great idea, but it's definitely working for me.

Say I draw "mu" or "iota", the Greek lowercase letters, perfectly. The score given would be between 25 and 50 in most cases. Dragging my finger from left to right or vice versa, drawing a perfect horizontal line, would trigger either mu or iota with scores of 20-30. That just shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding two gestures. One called "left" and one called "right" and they're shaped like horizontal lines. When predicting the closest gestures, it counts as a failure if left or right have the highest scores.

This prevents users from swiping left or right to draw a complex shape.